# How manufacturers lock their devices to run only software by them? And how it is possible at all?

Tags: operating-systems

How do manufacturers lock their devices to run only software by them? And how is it possible at all? For example: upgradeable toothbrush, mobile device, smart watch

Comment: Mostly they just don't give you a way to upgrade them. And when they do, they don't publish any source code or documentation, so nobody bothers to make different software.

Comment: I wonder about those cases where the manufacturer can upgrade their own software, but others cant't. I also don't wonder why it's more difficult for third parties to develop software for the device.

Answer (score 1):

Operating systems can verify that a particular code sequence originated from an authentic source using code signatures. This cryptographic technique verifies that a trusted entity - as identified by a public key - asserted the code sequence is authentic. To prevent a hardware device from being reprogrammed, the signature of the OS could be programmed into ROM and checked prior to boot. Thus, reprogramming the device would require intervening with the physical hardware. Realistically, most manufactures of low cost devices are not concerned with them being reprogrammed as this requires a lot of experience and devotion.

Comment: Operatin system? I think that operating systems don't block anything. I think the bootloader do, right?

Comment: "Realistically, most manufactures of low cost devices are not concerned with them being reprogrammed as this requires a lot of experience and devotion."? I asked about the devices that are locked.

Comment: I'm considering a situation in which you want to provide unsupervised updates. (This is how I interpreted your question.) In this situation to ensure system integrity, all code must be verified before it executed. This means the firmware checks the operating system and the operating system checks any external binaries. I've heard this referred to as an "appraisal chain." This is part of secure boot. You won't find this kind of technology in low cost devices because it requires a TPM.

Comment: Alternatively, you could check the integrity of each update update within the boot loader. (E.g. checks if the kernel is signed before executing it.) Assuming the boot loader is in read-only memory, this would work.

Comment: If the boot loader is responsible for validating the kernel, then updates to the boot loader would require physical interaction. (E.g. to enable write access.) If the device is able to be receive updates, it is able able to run arbitrary code. If someone has physical access and the resources, they can use your hardware to execute code. In many cases, they could just reprogram it through the JTAG or SPI interface.

Answer (score 1):

To run alternative software on a device, you need to be able to install the software somehow.

If the device runs software from a storage medium that can be removed, this is easy: attach the storage medium to a different computer, install the software onto this medium, and insert the medium back into the device. You can do that, for example, on a PC with a hard disk or detachable SSD drive. With this hardware configuration, if the device manufacturer wants to restrict permitted software, it has to boot on non-removable media (generally ROM or flash memory) which only runs software on other media under certain restrictions (generally requiring a cryptographic signature; this is commonly known as “secure boot”, though beware that terminology varies).

But embedded devices typically do not have a removable storage medium. Often they have a single chip with everything (main processor, RAM, flash memory, input-output controllers…), or at least a single board where all the components are soldered on. The only ways to access the device's storage medium are to interact with the software that's already there, or with costly physical methods (e.g. unsolder a component, or even shear the top off a chip).

Typically, if the manufacturer does not particularly care about updating the software after they've sold the device, they will not provide any easy way to update the software. It may still be possible, for example, to update the software through debug ports (if they're physically accessible), or through a generic operating system interface if the manufacturer has used an operating system with this capability.

If the manufacturer wants to be able to deploy updates, they will take care to make one method available to themselves. But if they didn't document it, it might take some effort to figure it out. And the manufacturer can put restrictions. For example, as above, the manufacturer might arrange that the device ships with functionality to download and install software updates, but this functionality checks that the software is cryptographically signed, so that only the manufacturer can make valid update images.

In all cases, there's a chain of the same form. What varies is the length of the parts.

1. When the processor starts, it runs code stored on a physically attached storage medium.
2. The code on this physically attached medium has restrictions on what other code it's willing to transfer control to.

Comment: The storage on an iPhone is encrypted using three keys - one in the processor, one random key stored in a known location on the storage drive, and one derived from your passcode. The first one makes it impossible to decrypt or encrypt any data unless you use the original processor. (In reality it's slightly more complicated).